# Memory warning on iOS 8 App - but usage is low

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, didreceivememorywarning

I hope someone can help me out, I already searched Stackoverflow and  Google but I couldn't get the right solution.
I am having a very simple app which takes a photo (using the standard iOS Camera through UIImagePickerController) then I save it to the file system with a very low resolution - `let thumbNailData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.02)` after that I display the images in a collection view using Core Data - I only save the filename in Core Data, not the image, image is only in the filesystem. 
So, however, when I run the app it shows me a memory usage of not more than 15 MB and Process is around 1-2 %. Everything runs fine but after adding 6-7 Photos I get strange errors like the Memory Warning, Lost connection to my iPhone and this on:

```
Communications error: <OS_xpc_error: <error: 0x198adfa80> { count = 1, contents =
    "XPCErrorDescription" => <string: 0x198adfe78> { length = 22, contents = "Connection interrupted"
```

So, I am really stuck is I thought I made it very lightweight and then I get these errors....
I already submitted a note taking app to the App Store which was much more high functionality than this one but this one runs very stable...

Any ideas?

Here is some of my code:
// Here I load the picture names into an array to display in the collection view

```
func loadColl () {
        let appDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate)
        let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!
        let fetchRequest:NSFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "PictureNote")
        var error:NSError?
        var result = context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &error) as [PictureNote]

        for res in result {
            println(res.latitude)
            println(res.longitude)
            println(res.longDate)
            println(res.month)
            println(res.year)
            println(res.text)
           pictures.append(res.thumbnail)
        }

    }
```

// Here is the code to display in collection view

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let myImageCell:ImageCell = myCollectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("imageCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as ImageCell
        myImageCell.imageCell.image = self.loadImageFromPath(fileInDocumentsDirectory(self.pictures[indexPath.row]))
        return myImageCell
    }
```

// Here is the code to load the pictures from disk

```
func loadImageFromPath(path: String) -> UIImage {
    let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: path)
    if image == nil {
        self.newAlert("Error loading your image, try again", title: "Notice")
    }
    return image!
}
```

// Here is my saving code

```
func saveNewEntry () {
        var unique = NSUUID().UUIDString
        var imageTitle = "Picture\(unique).jpg"
        var image = self.pickedImageView.image
        var path = fileInDocumentsDirectory(imageTitle)
        var thumbImageTitle = "ThumbPicture\(unique).jpg"
        var thumbPath = fileInDocumentsDirectory(thumbImageTitle)
        if self.saveImage(image!, path: path) == true && self.saveThumbImage(image!, thumbPath: thumbPath) == true {
            // Create the saving context
            let context = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate).managedObjectContext!
            let entityOne = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("PictureNote", inManagedObjectContext: context)
            let thisTask = PictureNote(entity: entityOne!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)
            // Get all the values here
            self.getMyLocation()
            var theDate = NSDate()
            thisTask.month = Date.toString(date: theDate, format: "MM")
            thisTask.year = Date.toString(date: theDate, format: "yyyy")
            thisTask.longDate = theDate
            thisTask.longitude = getMyLocation()[1]
            thisTask.latitude = getMyLocation()[0]
            thisTask.text = self.noteTextView.text
            thisTask.imageURL = imageTitle
            thisTask.thumbnail = thumbImageTitle
            thisTask.id = unique
            // Saving to CoreData
            if context.save(nil) {
                self.newAlert("Saving your note was successful!", title: "Notice")
                self.noteTextView.text = ""
            } else {
                 self.newAlert("Error saving your note, try again", title: "Notice")
            }

        } else {

          self.newAlert("Error saving your image, try again", title: "Notice")
        }


        self.pickedImageView.image = UIImage(named: "P1000342.jpg")
    }
```

I am really thankful for every suggestion....if you need more code, just let me know...

Comment: This is not memory warning, it is Apple's framework that cause this problem, this problem did happen some time before, maybe you can try update your Xcode and SDK.

Comment: search "XPCErrorDescription" for more information.

Comment: I know that, but I also receive a memory warning which I don't understand, it is in the text...

Comment: Well, I was running it on Xcode 6.1.3 and Xcode 6.2.5 ... both the same issue...

Comment: Also be wary of `UIImage(named:)`. You have one occurrence of that at the end of the method and I don't know if that's really a single hard-coded image that you use frequently (in which case, `UIImage(named:)` is fine) or whether it's indicative of using that initializer elsewhere, too).

Comment: When you ran this through Allocations tool in Instruments, did you see anything interesting?

Comment: I haven't seen anything interesting in the Allocations tool, all seems to be normal - that is why I am a bit confused... The one image with UIImage(named:..) is only 1 image which I use as a placeholder. And it also doesn't matter if I have 2 images loaded in the CollectionView or 10, the memory usage in analyzer is in both cases not higher than 20 MB which isn't that much. I will try with your answer and let you know if it worked... Thanks ahead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I notice that you are using a dramatically reduced quality factor in conjunction with `UIImageJPEGRepresentation`. If this is an attempt is to reduce the memory involved, all that does is reduce the size of the resulting `NSData` your write to persistent storage, but loading that image into the image view will still require something on the order of (4 × width × height) bytes (note, that's the dimensions of the image, not the image view). Thus the 3264 × 2448 image from a iPhone takes up 30mb per image, regardless of the quality factor employed by `UIImageJPEGRepresentation`.

Usually I will make sure my collection/table view uses thumbnail representation (either the `thumbnail` property of the `ALAsset` or [resize the default representation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28513086/1271826) myself). If I'm caching this thumbnail anywhere (such as persistent storage suggested by your question), I can then use a high quality representation of the thumbnail (I use PNG because it's lossless with compression, but JPEG with 0.7-0.9 quality factor is a reasonably faithful version, too).