# cropping(to: CGRect) doesn't crop correctly

Tags: swift, xcode, uiimage, crop, swift5

I am making a scanner for my app, but when I crop the image it always crops it incorrectly.

**The Cropping Rect Over The Image-**

[image]

**The Cropped Image-**

[image]

My Code for Cropping the Rect...

```
func croppedImage(rect: CGRect) -> UIImage {
    print("rect: \(rect)")
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, false, self.scale)

    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()! as CGContext

    let drawRect : CGRect = CGRect(x: -rect.origin.x, y: -rect.origin.y, width: self.size.width, height: self.size.height)

    context.clip(to: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: rect.size.width, height: rect.size.height))

    self.draw(in: drawRect)

    let croppedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return croppedImage
}
```

I have tried countless different code snippets to get the image to crop correctly and they all get the same outcome.

```
docVC.croppedImage = pdfImage.croppedImage(rect: croppingRect)
```

docVC is a view controller that I am passing the image into
pdfImage is the whole image that you see in the first picture
croppingRect is the rect which should be fine

I really need help with this, I have spent the last 2 hours trying to just crop one image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using one of the scaling content modes in your image view? If so, the dimensions of the image different from the dimensions of the image view and you have two options:

- You could just resize your image to match the dimensions of your image view before attempting the crop. Then a standard cropping routine would work. But that can result in either a loss of resolution or the introduction of pixelation.
- The better solution is to transform the cropping rectangle to the coordinates of the image dimensions before cropping.

For example:

```
extension UIImageView {
    func image(at rect: CGRect) -> UIImage? {
        guard
            let image = image,
            let rect = convertToImageCoordinates(rect)
        else {
            return nil
        }

        return image.cropped(to: rect)
    }

    func convertToImageCoordinates(_ rect: CGRect) -> CGRect? {
        guard let image = image else { return nil }

        let imageSize = CGSize(width: image.size.width, height: image.size.height)
        let imageCenter = CGPoint(x: imageSize.width / 2, y: imageSize.height / 2)

        let imageViewRatio = bounds.width / bounds.height
        let imageRatio = imageSize.width / imageSize.height

        let scale: CGPoint

        switch contentMode {
        case .scaleToFill:
            scale = CGPoint(x: imageSize.width / bounds.width, y: imageSize.height / bounds.height)

        case .scaleAspectFit:
            let value: CGFloat
            if imageRatio < imageViewRatio {
                value = imageSize.height / bounds.height
            } else {
                value = imageSize.width / bounds.width
            }
            scale = CGPoint(x: value, y: value)

        case .scaleAspectFill:
            let value: CGFloat
            if imageRatio > imageViewRatio {
                value = imageSize.height / bounds.height
            } else {
                value = imageSize.width / bounds.width
            }
            scale = CGPoint(x: value, y: value)

        case .center:
            scale = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 1)

        // unhandled cases include
        // case .redraw:
        // case .top:
        // case .bottom:
        // case .left:
        // case .right:
        // case .topLeft:
        // case .topRight:
        // case .bottomLeft:
        // case .bottomRight:

        default:
            fatalError("Unexpected contentMode")
        }

        var rect = rect
        if rect.width < 0 {
            rect.origin.x += rect.width
            rect.size.width = -rect.width
        }

        if rect.height < 0 {
            rect.origin.y += rect.height
            rect.size.height = -rect.height
        }

        return CGRect(x: (rect.minX - bounds.midX) * scale.x + imageCenter.x,
                      y: (rect.minY - bounds.midY) * scale.y + imageCenter.y,
                      width: rect.width * scale.x,
                      height: rect.height * scale.y)
    }
}
```

Now, I'm only handling four of the possible content modes, and if you want to handle more, you'd have to implement those yourself. But hopefully this illustrates the pattern, namely convert the selection `CGRect` into coordinates within the image before attempting the crop.

FWIW, this is the cropping method I use, `cropped(to:)` from https://stackoverflow.com/a/28513086/1271826, using the more contemporary `UIGraphicsImageRenderer`, using CoreGraphics cropping if I can, etc. But use whatever cropping routine you want, but just make sure to transform the coordinates to something suitable for the image.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, I have been trying for hours. It is my first time working with image cropping and such. Thank you again.

Comment: i want to give you upvote from everywhere you god !