# How to align UILabels with SF Symbols and custom images in UITableViewCell's imageView?

Tags: ios, sf-symbols

What I want to achive is something like list view in Files App. Document will display a little thumbnail if has one. Otherwise a SF Symbol with textStyle `.callout` will show up. **All the rows’ labels should be left aligned.** But currently the thumbnails are much bigger than the SF Symbols so that they push the labels away.

I emphasize **textStyle** because my app supports dynamic type, which means the `imageView`'s frame calculation should base on SF Symbol.

I try to override `layoutSubviews`. But can't figure out how to do the calculation.

#### Files App

[image: Files App]

#### My App

[image: My App]

Comment: If you are using SF Symbols, you're already requiring iOS 13+. Have you checked out the new features in UICollectionView for iOS 14? IIRC, one of the "list" features align things like this. Use the Apple Developer app - I think - check out Modern cell configuration.

Comment: Not quite clear what you're going for... In your "My App" image, do you want the 4 images to be the same size as the `doc.text` symbol on the first row?

Comment: @DonMag I should be more clear. The texts of each row should be aligned. The first row is an example how all rows should look like.

Comment: @dfd I just watched a section of WWDC 20 and it seemed promising. But I am a little reluctant to adopt since it looks like more work to do.

Comment: @francisfeng You have to give fixed width and height to make them align.

Comment: @francisfeng - still need some detail... Do you want it to look like this,  with the images scaled to proportionally to 60x60 (that is, maintaining aspect ratio)? https://i.stack.imgur.com/IA30X.png  Here's the same output, but with a border around the image view for clarity: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ypKSp.png

Comment: @DonMag Yes. This is exactly what I want. How do you acheive it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For maximum control of your cell appearance, you should create a custom cell. But, if you want use a standard `Subtitle` cell, you can resize your images when setting them.

There are some excellent image scaling functions in this Stack Overflow answer: [how to resize a bitmap on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28512212/how-to-resize-a-bitmap-on-ios/28513086#28513086)

Add the extensions from that answer to your project. Specifically, for your needs, we'll use `scaledAspectFit()`.

So, assuming you have a `Subtitle` cell prototype, with identifier of "cell", your `cellForRowAt` will look something like this:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    
    // however you have your data stored
    let title = "IMG_0001.JPG"
    let subtitle = "Today at 10:15 AM, 2.5 MB"
    let imgName = "IMG_0001"
    
    cell.textLabel?.text = title
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = subtitle
    
    if let img = UIImage(named: imgName) {
        // default cell image size is 56x56 (points)
        //  so we'll proportionally scale the image,
        //  using screen scale to get the best resolution
        let widthHeight = UIScreen.main.scale * 56
        let scaledImg = img.scaledAspectFit(to: CGSize(width: widthHeight, height: widthHeight))
        cell.imageView?.image = scaledImg
    }
    return cell

}
```

---

**Edit**

Takes only a little research to implement the use fo SF Symbols...

Add this func to your table view controller - it will return a `UIImage` of an SF Symbol at specified point size, centered in specified size:

```
private func drawSystemImage(_ sysName: String, at pointSize: CGFloat, centeredIn size: CGSize) -> UIImage? {
    let cfg = UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(pointSize: pointSize)
    guard let img = UIImage(systemName: sysName, withConfiguration: cfg) else { return nil }
    let x = (size.width - img.size.width) * 0.5
    let y = (size.height - img.size.height) * 0.5
    let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: size)
    return renderer.image { context in
        img.draw(in: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: x, y: y), size: img.size))
    }
}
```

Then change your `cellForRowAt` func as needed:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    
    // however you have your data stored
    let title = "IMG_0001.JPG"
    let subtitle = "Today at 10:15 AM, 2.5 MB"
    let imgName = "IMG_0001"
    
    cell.textLabel?.text = title
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = subtitle

    // defalt image view size
    let wh = UIScreen.main.scale * 56
    let targetSize = CGSize(width: wh, height: wh)

    // for this example, if it's the first row, generate an image from SF Symbol
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        if let img = drawSystemImage("doc.text", at: UIScreen.main.scale * 24, centeredIn: targetSize) {
            cell.imageView?.image = img
        }
    } else {
        if let img = UIImage(named: imgName) {
            // default cell image size is 56x56 (points)
            //  so we'll proportionally scale the image,
            //  using screen scale to get the best resolution
            let scaledImg = img.scaledAspectFit(to: targetSize)
            cell.imageView?.image = scaledImg
        }
    }
    return cell
    
}
```

I'll leave it up to you to tweak the point size as desired (and configure any other properties of your SF Symbol image such as weight, scale, color, etc).

Comment: I know how to resize images. But this answer didn't involve SF symbols, which in my case it's crucial to align them with images.

Comment: @francisfeng - rather easy to do... see my edited answer. (With a little searching, you could probably have made the changes yourself in the time it took me to post the edit).